# Could not load file or assembly CMS.DataEngine - after Kentico 11.0.0 upgrade to Kentico 12 SP1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, content-management-system, kentico

I have got the following error after upgrading Kentico 11 to Kentico 12 SP1.

The action I have made:
1. I have removed all the reference of Kentico dll and I added new reference.
2. All the DLL (both at solution and the published website) in BIN folder and VS belong to version 12, not 11 as written on the error. Also the associated dependency (I have it with ILSPY) .
3. I removed all the file at C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/
4. I cleared cache and reset IIS.
5. That assembly doesn't appeared on any file on my solution (even not in WEB.config) .
6. I check the file of the project Web.csproj and it contain the assembly (CMS.DataEngine) without the version,Culture and PublicKeyToken - I added it like other assembly of kentico
There is no sign of version 11.0.0.0 , so why the website searching after that version ???

Thank you,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you received any errors during the upgrade, this could cause the DLLs to not update in the /Lib directory.

I suggest going to the /Lib directory and checking the file properties to ensure you have file versions of 12.0.xxx and not something with version 11.0.xxx.  There should be no need to manually re-add/update the references in the project after an upgrade.

After you verify your DLL version in the /Lib directory, then delete the /CMS/Bin directory and rebuild your application.

Comment: Hi Brenden,
I did that action a lot of time.
All the DLL files of Kentico in those path belong to version 12:
- CMS/Bin
- Custom Projects/Bin
-Lib
-Bin folder in the published website.

All the DLL reference of Kentico in VS  are version 12.

There is no sign to version 11

Comment: @idan Do you have binding redirects in your `web.config` that tell ASP.NET to try and load an older version (11.0) of the `CMS.DataEngine` assembly?

Comment: @idan Sometimes another assembly that is looking for a specific version of a dependent assembly could cause the wrong version to be loaded.

Check your `/bin` for any `11.0.x` `CMS.*.dll` files

Comment: If you have custom assembly project, remove all references to Kentico DLLs and re-add them back, selecting the v12 DLLs.

Comment: @seangwright I did it with CMS.DataEngine, but I have got the same error with CMS.Core . When I Added redirect to CMS.Core, I have got error that the key already exists.
I would like to find what exactly the source of that error instead of to perform workaround.
Thank You

Comment: I'd suggest installing a new instance of Kentico and reviewing the web.config file and references to make sure you're project is setup correctly. We validate this with EVERY upgrade we perform.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
The Lib folder was exist inside the folder of the solution with file explorer, but unlike the previous version (Kentico 11), when I have performed the upgrade, the Lib folder was not under the solution in visual studio!
I have added the folder in visual studio under the solution with all the DLL and XML files from Lib folder. I have perform "clean solution", build all the projects and published it.
Now it works.